# How to make the whole record readonly in openerp7

Tags: odoo

I know to make a field readonly with the "readonly" attribute. Is it possible to make the entire record readonly. That means that all field in a form should be readonly on a condition.

One insignificant way i found is to make this **attrs="{'readonly':[('state','=','close')]}"** in all the fileds present in the form.

```
<field name="responsible_id" class="oe_inline" attrs="{'readonly':
<field name="type" attrs="{ 'readonly':[('state','=','close')]}" class="oe_inline"/>
<field name="send_response" attrs="{'readonly':[('state','=','close')]}"/>[('state','=','close')]}"/>
```

However i don't think this be the right one. I expect some way to put readonly attribut common for the form. Kindly suggest.

In my example, People can view all the records and edit only their own records.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your Python imports:

```
from lxml import etree
from openerp.osv.orm import setup_modifiers
```

And modify the fields in the `fields_view_get` method like this:

```
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type=None, context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):

    res = super(MyClass, self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id=view_id, view_type=view_type,
                                                        context=context, toolbar=toolbar, submenu=submenu)

    if view_type == 'form':
        # Set all fields read only when state is close.
        doc = etree.XML(res['arch'])
        for node in doc.xpath("//field"):
            node.set('attrs', "{'readonly': [('state', '=', 'close')]}")
            node_name = node.get('name')
            setup_modifiers(node, res['fields'][node_name])

        res['arch'] = etree.tostring(doc)

    return res
```

This will modify every field on the form to include the `attrs="{'readonly':[('state','=','close')]}"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

put a group on entire form and use `attrs` to make it read only.